# HALF_EVEN rounding doesn't work

Tags: java, rounding, decimalformat

I've read several articles about using decimal format and rounding and I think I am using it correctly, but somehow HALF_EVEN, HALF_DOWN or HALF_UP rounding doesn't work.
Do you have any ideas if it has something to do with eclipse settings or do I really use the decimalformat incorrectly?

My goal is to round every number from .55 to .6 like in standard mathematical rounding. So...as I assumed...the best option is to round with "HALF_UP".

Code:

```
import java.math.RoundingMode;
import java.text.DecimalFormat;

public class Rounding {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat();
        df.setMinimumFractionDigits(1);
        df.setMaximumFractionDigits(1);
        df.setRoundingMode(RoundingMode.HALF_UP);


        for (double x = 0.55; x < 10.0; x++) {
            System.out.println("Original value: " + x + "\tRounded value: " + df.format(x));
        }
    }
}
```

Result:

```
Original value: 0.55    Rounded value: 0,6
Original value: 1.55    Rounded value: 1,6
Original value: 2.55    Rounded value: 2,5
Original value: 3.55    Rounded value: 3,5
Original value: 4.55    Rounded value: 4,5
Original value: 5.55    Rounded value: 5,5
Original value: 6.55    Rounded value: 6,5
Original value: 7.55    Rounded value: 7,5
Original value: 8.55    Rounded value: 8,6
Original value: 9.55    Rounded value: 9,6
```

Comment: `System.out.printf("%s %s%n", df.format(0.44), df.format(0.45));` will output `0.4` and `0.5` respectively.

Answer (score 3):

Once you have the numbers in `double` format you have already created hidden inaccuracy that can round numbers under or over the halfway mark without you seeing it.

You'll need to use BigDecimal.

Comment: If you wrap 3.55 in BigDecimal and try to format it will show 3.5 as result too.

Comment: Or add a very small amount before rounding so you’re sure you’re on the up side of, say, 2.55. Like `1e-10`. This is standard practice.

Comment: @eg04lt3r that's why you need to write BigDecimal.valueOf("3.55") in quotes.

Comment: Thank you for your answers. Adding 1e-10 will be enough for my purposes. Many thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

To understand how this rounding works internally, add `System.out.println("exact x: " + new BigDecimal(x));` inside the loop. It will print the exact value of x, compared to your current code, which only prints an approximate value.

When you understand what happens, fix your code by using integer arithmetic instead of floating point arithmetic wherever possible.

Comment: Thank you for your answer :)